# jQuery error "Access denied" in IE browser

Tags: jquery

My all project is working fine ,
But in IE i found this error,
I am stacked for this error what should i make changes for this

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
jquery-1.4.2.min.js, line 127 character 344
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running your site locally? IEs local security settings usually mess things up, try uploading it to a server.

Comment: It's already in live server